# Architecture of autoencoders

Tags: autoencoders

Ordinary autoencoder architectures (not variational autoencoders, stacked denoising autoencoders, etc.) seem to only have three layers: the input, the hidden/code, and the output/reconstruction. Are there any examples of papers which used architectures consisting of multiple hidden layers? If not, what are the theoretical justifications for only using one hidden layer in an autoencoder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are there any examples of papers which used architectures consisting of multiple hidden layers?

Yes, e.g. look for "[deep autoencoders](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=deep+autoencoders&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C22&as_sdtp=)" a.k.a. "[stacked autoencoders](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=stacked+autoencoders&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C22&as_sdtp=)", such as {1}:

[image]

Hugo Larochelle has the video on it: [Neural networks [7.6] : Deep learning - deep autoencoder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5ZYm_wJ37c)

Geoffrey Hinton also has a video on it: [Lecture 15.2 — Deep autoencoders [Neural Networks for Machine Learning]](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks)

---

Examples of deep autoencoders which don't make use of pretraining: http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Stacked_Autoencoders

> A good way to obtain good parameters for a stacked autoencoder is to use greedy layer-wise training.

E.g., {2} uses a stacked autoencoder with greedy layer-wise training.

Note that one can use autoencoders fancier  than feedforward fully connected neural networks, e.g. {3}.

---

References:

- {1} Hinton, Geoffrey E., and Ruslan R. Salakhutdinov. "Reducing the dimensionality of data with neural networks." science 313, no. 5786 (2006): 504-507. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Reducing+the+Dimensionality+of+Data+with+Neural+Networks&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C22&as_sdtp= ;
  https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/science.pdf (~5k citations)
- {2} Heydarzadeh, Mehrdad, Mehrdad Nourani, and Sarah Ostadabbas. "In-bed posture classification using deep autoencoders." In Engineering in Medicine and Biology Society (EMBC), 2016 IEEE 38th Annual International Conference of the, pp. 3839-3842. IEEE, 2016. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=16153787462804186587&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22
- {3} Aaron van den Oord, Nal Kalchbrenner, Oriol Vinyals, Lasse Espeholt, Alex Graves, Koray Kavukcuoglu. Conditional Image Generation with PixelCNN Decoders. NIPS 2016. https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05328 ; http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6527-tree-structured-reinforcement-learning-for-sequential-object-localization.pdf

Comment: I'm more interested in examples of deep autoencoders which don't make use of pretraining using RBMs, but are trained end-to-end using backprop with random weight initializations. However, this is also very interesting, and it could be the case that every deep autoencoder makes use of pretraining.

Comment: @liangjy I see, answer edited.  To obtain good parameters for a feedforward stacked autoencoder one often uses greedy layer-wise training.